# modifying this beautiful number ticker

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a beautiful Number Ticker. the whole day I was wondering and trying to modify the code to make it as I want but no success till now!

if you work with numbers with two or more digits then the code creates separate black squares to hold each digit ( run code snippet to have a look ), but I want only a single square as the container to hold multiple digit numbers. So if we have a two-digit number like **10** the Number Ticker should be something like this:

[image]

And the next move should look like :

[image]

I don't want those parallel animations that move two digits like this (Only the single animation is required not both):

[image]

Here is the code:

```js
let counters = document.getElementsByClassName('number-ticker');

let defaultDigitNode = document.createElement('div');
defaultDigitNode.classList.add('digit');

for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  defaultDigitNode.innerHTML += i + '<br>';
}

[].forEach.call(counters, function(counter) {
  let currentValue = 10;
  let digits = [];

  generateDigits(currentValue.toString().length);
  setValue(currentValue);

  setTimeout(function() {
    setValue(8);
  }, 2000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    setValue(7);
  }, 5000);

  function setValue(number) {
    let s = number.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
    let l = s.length;

    if (l > digits.length) {
      generateDigits(l - digits.length);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
      setDigit(i, s[i] || 0);
    }
  }

  function setDigit(digitIndex, number) {
    digits[digitIndex].style.marginTop = '-' + number + 'em';
  }

  function generateDigits(amount) {
    for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
      let d = defaultDigitNode.cloneNode(true);
      counter.appendChild(d);
      digits.unshift(d);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25vh;
  font-family: Roboto Light;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.number-ticker {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: #333;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.05em black inset;
}

.number-ticker .digit {
  float: left;
  line-height: 1;
  transition: margin-top 1.75s ease;
  border-right: 1px solid #555;
  padding: 0 0.075em;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Number Ticker</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="number-ticker.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="number-ticker" data-value="0"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="number-ticker.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue in your code is the `digits` variable. It creates an array of HTML elements that holds two blocks.

Also, for this line:
`let s = number.toString().split('').reverse().join('');`
Why do you need to convert number to a string. You can just pass it as is. Once you add to a string using + it will be converted.

I made few changes to your code and commented out the non-relevant part. Please see below:

```js
let counters = document.getElementsByClassName('number-ticker');

let defaultDigitNode = document.createElement('div');
defaultDigitNode.classList.add('digit');

for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  defaultDigitNode.innerHTML += i + '<br>';
}

[].forEach.call(counters, function(counter) {

  // let currentValue = 10;
  // let digits = [];
  let currentValue = counter.getAttribute("data-value");
  let digit = null;

  generateDigits(currentValue.toString().length);
  setValue(currentValue);

  setTimeout(function() {
    setValue(8);
  }, 2000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    setValue(7);
  }, 5000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    setValue(10);
  }, 8000);

  function setValue(number) {

   // let s = number.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
   // let l = s.length;
    /*if (l > digits.length) {
      generateDigits(l - digits.length);
    }*/

    /*for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
      setDigit(i, s[i] || 0);
    }*/
 
    digit.style.marginTop = '-' + number + 'em';
  }
 
 
  /*function setDigit(digitIndex, number) {
    console.log(number);
    digits[digitIndex].style.marginTop = '-' + number + 'em';
  }*/

  function generateDigits(amount) {
    //  console.log("generat", amount);
    //  for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    let d = defaultDigitNode.cloneNode(true);
    digit = counter.appendChild(d);
    // digits.unshift(d);
    //  }
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25vh;
  font-family: Roboto Light;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.number-ticker {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: #333;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.05em black inset;
}

.number-ticker .digit {
  float: left;
  line-height: 1;
  transition: margin-top 1.75s ease;
  border-right: 1px solid #555;
  padding: 0 0.075em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="number-ticker" data-value="0"></div>
</div>
```

Your final JS could be like this:

```
let counters = document.getElementsByClassName('number-ticker');

let defaultDigitNode = document.createElement('div');
defaultDigitNode.classList.add('digit');

for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  defaultDigitNode.innerHTML += i + '<br>';
}

[].forEach.call(counters, function(counter) {
  let currentValue = counter.getAttribute("data-value");
    let d = defaultDigitNode.cloneNode(true);
  let digit = counter.appendChild(d);

  setValue(currentValue);

  function setValue(number) {
    digit.style.marginTop = '-' + number + 'em';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your css has this

```css
.number-ticker .digit {
  float: left;
  line-height: 1;
  transition: margin-top 1.75s ease;
  border-right: 1px solid #555;
  padding: 0 0.075em;
}
```

You need to change it to this

```css
 .number-ticker .digit {
     float: left;
     line-height: 1;
     transition: margin-top 1.75s ease;
     padding: 0 0.075em;
   text-align: center;
}
```

If you remove `border-right: 1px solid #555` you will have it look like 1 box.

Also I added `text-align: center` to center the numbers.

Hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer plus one ... But I think a miss understanding happed... I've edited my question ...

Comment: quick question. do you want animation at all?
and do you want to have '10' then '9' or '10' then '09'

Comment: @ Mileta Dulovic yes the animation is required I think and  I want the function intact so we can update the counter. Yes maybe we want to have '10' then '9' or '10' then '09'

Comment: to be honest I don't think that you can change animation with the way function works now. I think that you'll need to change function in order to make it work the way you want it. Someone please correct me if I am wrong